# Ubuntu server install failing under Hyper-V

Tags: server, system-installation, hyper-v

- Windows 10 Pro with Hyper-V enabled.
- Latest Ubuntu 16.10 x64 server iso.
- Created a new Hyper-V vm with defaults, 20GB vhd, 2 cpu's, 2GB
  memory, virtual switch, mounted the iso and started install.
- VM is Gen 2. I disabled Secure Boot in the firmware settings, read a
  number of articles that by doing so Gen2 was supported in Linux and
  esp in Ubuntu.
- It was able to access the internet and downloaded packages while
  installing.
- Chose all defaults, let LVM partition disk, let it install GRUB,
  again with all defaults.

But when I start the VM I get a screen saying no OS can be found. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well a while back. I simply resolved it by installing it as a Generation 1 VM. As long as you are willing to give up the extra features of Generation 2 (UEFI, larger max storage, secure boot which you yourself said you aren't using, etc) then you could give a Generation 1 VM a shot.